# Pulse directory not in /run/user/UID

Tags: linux, pulseaudio

When trying to start an application that uses pulse I keep running into the following error:

```
Failed to create secure directory (/run/user/40445/pulse): No such file or directory
```

This makes sense because the directory `/run/user/40445/` does not have Pulse in it. I was wondering why this is. How can I add this directory?

Note: user 40445 is a regular user without root access and the application being run is the Carla Simulator (although the problem should not be specific to this application).

Comment: What is the user running this? (`id 40445`)

Comment: @thanasisp yes, 40445 is the user id.

Comment: I mean, is it a regular user, or some user dedicated to a service, how you run it, etc. It could be related to permissions. Also "an application that uses pulse" what application? (anything of them that you think could be helpful, please add into the question)

Comment: @thanasisp I updated the question, let me know if I am still missing information that might be important.